# How can we convert a Bitmap object to a complex number?

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, bitmap, complex-numbers

How to convert **Bitmap** to **Complex Number**?

```
        public static COMPLEX [,] BitmapToComplex2D(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            COMPLEX[,] comp = new COMPLEX[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];

            int [,] array2D = BitmapToArray2D(bmp);

            for (int i = 0; i <= bmp.Width - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= bmp.Height - 1; j++)
                {
                    comp[i,j].RealPart = ???;
                    comp[i,j].ImaginaryPart = ???;
                }
            }

            return comp;
        }
```

Given that...

**2D array to Bitmap converter**

```
public static Bitmap Array2DToBitmap(int[,] image)
        {
            int i, j;
            Bitmap output = new Bitmap(image.GetLength(0), image.GetLength(1));
            BitmapData bitmapData1 = output.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.GetLength(0), image.GetLength(1)),
                                     ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            unsafe
            {
                byte* imagePointer1 = (byte*)bitmapData1.Scan0;
                for (i = 0; i < bitmapData1.Height; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < bitmapData1.Width; j++)
                    {
                        imagePointer1[0] = (byte)image[j, i];
                        imagePointer1[1] = (byte)image[j, i];
                        imagePointer1[2] = (byte)image[j, i];
                        imagePointer1[3] = 255;
                        //4 bytes per pixel
                        imagePointer1 += 4;
                    }//end for j
                    //4 bytes per pixel
                    imagePointer1 += (bitmapData1.Stride - (bitmapData1.Width * 4));
                }//end for i
            }//end unsafe
            output.UnlockBits(bitmapData1);

            return output;// col;
        }
```

**2D complex number to Bitmap**  (Is it correct?)

```
        public static Bitmap Complex2DToBitmap(COMPLEX[,] comp)
        {
            Bitmap output = new Bitmap(comp.GetLength(0), comp.GetLength(1));

            int[,] GreyscaleImage2DArray = new int[output.Width, output.Height];

            for (int i = 0; i <= output.Width - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= output.Height - 1; j++)
                {
                    GreyscaleImage2DArray[i, j] = (int)comp[i, j].Magnitude();
                }
            }

            output = ImageConverter.Array2DToBitmap(GreyscaleImage2DArray);

            return output;
        }
```

Comment: In `Array2DToBitmap` you cast `int` to `byte`, are you sure all values on `image` are between 0 and 255?

Comment: I am only working with grayscale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of enconding the magnitude of the each complex number I would encode the real part and imaginary part separated, on different pixels.

```
public static Bitmap Complex2DToBitmap(COMPLEX[,] comp)
{
   Bitmap output = new Bitmap(comp.GetLength(0), comp.GetLength(1));

   // Double the width for storing real and imaginary parts on different pixels.
   int[,] GreyscaleImage2DArray = new int[output.Width * 2, output.Height]; 

   // Increase the step to 2, and decrease the limit by 1.
   for (int i = 0; i <= output.Width - 2; i+=2) 
   {
       for (int j = 0; j <= output.Height - 1; j++)
       {
           // Store RealPart and ImaginaryPart on different pixels.
           GreyscaleImage2DArray[i, j] = (int)comp[i, j].RealPart;
           GreyscaleImage2DArray[i+1, j] = (int)comp[i, j].ImaginaryPart;
       }
   }

   output = ImageConverter.Array2DToBitmap(GreyscaleImage2DArray);

   return output;
}

public static COMPLEX [,] BitmapToComplex2D(Bitmap bmp)
{
    // Halve the width, each complex is stored in 2 pixels.
    COMPLEX[,] comp = new COMPLEX[(int)(bmp.Width / 2), bmp.Height];

    int [,] array2D = BitmapToArray2D(bmp);

    for (int i = 0; i <= bmp.Width - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= bmp.Height - 1; j++)
        {
            comp[i, j].RealPart = array2D[i * 2, j];
            comp[i, j].ImaginaryPart = array2D[i * 2 + 1, j];
        }
    }

    return comp;
}
```